# SSRS Parse UniqueName of a member to display it as date in Using MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

here is my problem

[Time].[Month Hierarchy].[Day].&[2006]&[2]&[26]

how to parse the UniqueName above to display like this --> 2006/2/26 using mdx or expression in ssrs

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression below.
Change the field name to match your own.

```
= Replace(Replace(Replace(Mid(Fields!Day.value,33,16),']',''),'[',''),'&','/')
```

Comment: An alternative could be the use of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace

Answer (score 0):

If you know than every level contains the appropiate member_key you could use the VB date functions:

```
With Member Measures.Date As DATESERIAL( 
Ancestor([Time].[Month Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Time].[Month Hierarchy].[YEAR_LEVEL]).MEMBER_KEY, 
Ancestor([Time].[Month Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Time].[Month Hierarchy].[MONTH_LEVEL]).MEMBER_KEY,
[Time].[Month Hierarchy].CurrentMember.MEMBER_KEY)
Select 
{Measures.Date} On Columns,
{[Time].[Month Hierarchy].[Day].&[2006]&[2]&[26]} On Rows 
From [YOUR_CUBE]
```